# I think the 'total score' label on the top users page should be changed

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, top-users

On the user's tags page (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=tags), I think labelling (via tool-tip) the number next to the tag as 'total score' is misleading. It is apparently calculated by the number of votes the answers provided by a user has received, however reputation is also referred to as 'reputation score' in the tool-tip.
I wondered why my score for certain tags was not higher as it should score 10 for a voted answer.

I think replacing score from the tool-tip text to would be clearer, for example 'total votes'.

[image: Annotated example screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I would like to fix this, however "total votes" is not working for me ... it could mean the total number of votes OR total of the votes.

Comment: How about "vote total" or "votes score"?

Comment: Well, all of the questions on the frontpage have their "votes" displayed and labeled as such, even though "score" is the correct term (upvote minus downvote) so I don't think this is a issue

Comment: I like "vote total"

Comment: @waffles, do you like "vote total" enough that this will eventually be changed?  (I still see and was confused by the tooltip text that says "total score" on the [top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers) page.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that "Total Score" is misleading.  How about "Vote Count"?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe they can provide an AJAX tool-tip with a question mark linking to a description of the metric. The regular HTML tooltips are a little awkward, they're not as friendly / reliable as AJAX ones and also can't provide a contextual help link with more information.

I guess I can see how "Total Votes" could be misleading.  Maybe "Total Number of Votes".  Then again, maybe "Total Number of Unique Votes".  This was the point in my line of reasoning where I said - "shoot, they just need to link out to a page explaining it".