# Confusing 'total score' terminology

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

On the tag-wiki pages :

> To edit this wiki, you must have a
>   total score of 100 on
>   non-community-wiki answers in this tag
>   (you currently have 9), and at least
>   2000 reputation

I find 'total score' confusing. If I understand properly total score is not the amount of up-votes but represents the number of up-votes minus the down-votes. Or am I wrong again ?

Why use a third unit ? Can't we just translate everything into these shiny rep points ?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28425/i-think-the-total-score-label-on-the-tags-stats-page-should-be-changed

Answer (score 4):

Daily reputation cap, and acceptances.

Votes do not translate simply into rep. Even after you have controlled for Community Wikiness.

- There is a upper limit (200) on the number of points you can earn each day from (upvotes-downvotes) on questions and answers.
- Acceptances would effectively give askers 2.5 votes in that matter of how expert you are. Are they really the people best equipped to judge?

So you'd have to be talking about *"nominal reputation from votes if you had gotten credit for all of them"* or some similar dense verbiage. Ugh.

Comment: In this case it wouldn't be votes translated into rep but 'total score' replaced by a near equivalent in reputation points. And acceptances doesn't give 2.5 votes but 15 rep points (you could have 0 vote). I'm voluntarily nitpicking to show how this 'total score' name is confusing. When I hear score I think of points but points are rep...

Answer (score 2):

**Why use a third unit ? Can't we just translate everything into these shiny rep points ?**

It's not because you have a lot of reputation that you know well all the tag on this site. In fact, it's impossible. We want to make sure only the people that know a specific tag well can edit the wiki. When someone as gain a lot of upvote on a specific tag, it usually mean he knows that tag well.

Comment: I wasn't discussing the desire to check the knowledge for the specific tag. I meant translate '100 total score' into it's equivalent in reputation, which would be about a 1000.

Comment: To clarify my former comment : 1000 reputation on non-community-wiki answers in this tag

Comment: Rep is not equivalent to score * 10. If I had 150 upvotes and 150 downvotes in a tag then opinion of my knowledge of that tag is clearly divided, however that would give me rep of 1350 within the tag.

Comment: @mikej In SO 'rules' it is accepted that up-votes weigh more than down-votes, why would it be different in this case. I admit I haven't checked the db but I would imagine users with at least 100 upvotes on a specific tag would rarely have, even half of that amount, in downvotes. It's a wiki after all so why bother with a corner case like that.

Comment: @mikej: 150*10 + 150*-2 = 1200

Comment: @Gnome (blush) yes, I think I must have been thinking -1 for each downvote for some odd reason.