# Tag Info | users | total score

Tags: discussion, top-users

When I look at my total all time score on the wxwidgets tag it shows 5. ( [wxwidgets top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wxwidgets/topusers) )

This does not seem correct.  For instance, my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597253/how-to-allow-user-to-order-columns-with-wxlistctrl-in-report-mode/1603249#1603249) was accepted and upvoted once.  So it seems I should have a score of at least 35.

---

Oh, I see that the "total score" is the number of upvotes, not the reputation total. ( [explanation of top-user score issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28425/i-think-the-total-score-label-on-the-top-users-page-should-be-changed)  )Seems strange that accepted answers do not count.

Comment: note: your username on top users list can only seen by you. thats for your reference.

Comment: yes it should be in the tooltip because i had to do this search to figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]